# BlackBerry - Attribute Entry-Point-Icon: file cannot be found

Tags: blackberry, icons, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to pack and sign my Adobe Air 2.5 app for the PlayBook through the "BlackBerry Tabelt OS Graphical Aid".

I'm running into this error:

> Warning: Using default icon: C:\Programme\Research In
>   Motion\blackberry-tablet-sdk-2.0.0\bin..\samples\icons\blackberry-tablet-default-icon.png
>   Error: Attribute Entry-Point-Icon: file cannot be found in the list of
>   packaged files: blackberry-tablet-icon.png

My blackberry-tablet.xml file:

```
<qnx>
    <icon>
        <image>blackberry-tablet-icon.png</image>
    </icon>
    <author>Foo Bar</author>
    <category>core.games</category>
    <splashscreen>xyz_splash_landscape.png</splashscreen>
    <buildId>100</buildId>
    <platformVersion>2.0.0.0</platformVersion>
</qnx>
```

Any ideas where the error comes from?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see, when running "c:\Programme\Research In Motion\blackberry-tablet-sdk-2.0.0\bin\blackberry-airpackager.bat" at the command line?

Comment: There is no output, just the error message from above. I'm using this tool to pack and sign the app: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Tablet-OS-Graphical-Aid/ta-p/1207067 (Not the pure command line way) - Do I need to set an absolut or relative path to the icon file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the icon in the Package using "Add additional files".

Comment: Can you please show me an blackberry-tablet.xml file example with that "Add additional files" element?  I'm still struggling with that error...